# Getting Mongoose virtual properties with Passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I'm trying to access some virtual properties defined in a mongoose model from passport user object in the request, but all I get are persistent fields.

Is there some way of getting the virtual properties without querying again?

**Edit:**

model:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstname: {
        type: String,
    },
    lastname: {
        type: String,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
});

UserSchema.virtual('fullName').get(function() {
   return (this.firstname + this.lastname); 
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

user controller:

```
exports.sayHi = function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('Hi ' + req.user.fullName);
}
```

passport config:

```
var User = mongoose.model('User');

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findOne({
            _id: id
        },
        '-password',
        function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Show your model and the passport part

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly done.